WinError 225. Unable to install gradio library on my pc
I am trying to run a program which requires gradio to be installed. When i try to install it using pip command it gives me WinError 225.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
WinError 225
I have tried installing by disabling the antivirus on my computer, but the error remains.
How this issue can be resolved ?.

Which antivirus is that? How did you disable it?
